# Editing long questions in stages

Tags: discussion, support, editing

I have tried several times now to start on editing a long question that needs serious reformatting. But halfway through someone else edits the question and I can't (or don't feel I shouldn't) finish my edit, but start over.

Therefore I have started to edit part of the question and the "save" the change before going on. I was wondering if this is an acceptable approach when editing longer questions?

I, of course, understand that repeated editing isn't desirable, but is it just a bit frustrating sometimes when I waste minutes editing a question.

Comment: I'm guessing the arose out of a question I saw you do this on. Ironically enough, it sparked my interest as well since I was going to go through and edit what you didn't  ;) (+1)

Comment: I think that's ok. But you should be aware of the feature of the software that after 10 edits your answer becomes CW (and won't earn you any rep). That can be overturned, but requires moderator action. And it is best not to burden moderators with chores like this, if you can avoid it (sometimes you cannot, because the OP is being edited at a tremendous clip).

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, I would like to post my thoughts on this question.

First thought, would be to say that, no this isn't really an accept method of editing.

If you feel your edits were bad, or you'd like to format them in another way and want to start over, sure it's a waste to not save them. But in the mean time, the edit is half finished and leaves something to be desired for others who are looking to edit posts.

I'd recommend just starting over on your edit. If someone happens to edit before you, just copy your edit and see if there was anything that you can substantially change to make the post better.

Comment: Wouldn't blocking new edits while a question/answer is already being edited be a better solution?