# Edit in progress warning

Tags: feature-request, editing

I often feel it is a waste of time when you are editing a question and shortly before you finish you see that the question already got edited, and your edit does not improve the corrections which were already made.

It would be nice if there is a "warning" that for the question there is already someone who takes care of it, or there is "editing in progress", so you might review it later.

Seems related to this: [Editing long questions in stages](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8917/editing-long-questions-in-stages)

Which is 7 years old, and nothing changed.
I do think that this is a problem (maybe minor), but a comfort change for users who take care of poorly written questions, is desireable in my opinion.

Comment: As a low-tech stop-gap solution, could an editor not post a comment saying that they're editing before they start, and then delete it when they're done?

Comment: Might consider it, when I go for a detailed edit next time. But I feel like that this encourages a "who is first to edit" mentality, or is at least data waste, and not really practical.

Comment: Not solving your problem, but in my experience when a post has several formatting issues, it is better to first comment to clarify. If you edit right away, it is likely that the OP will submit several small edit in a short period of time, which nullified your edit every time.

Comment: In cases where an inexperienced user makes a series of minor (usually unhelpful) edits, each time blocking a more thorough re-formatting, I have left a comment asking them to refrain from editing for a few minutes.  Of course, this doesn't help if multiple third parties are trying to edit simultaneously.

Comment: @lulu For me the main issue is in really long posts, where someone new to this site does not use MathJax, and you try to fix that, what is easy but can be real Sisyphos work, which can take several minutes. So the more detailed you are trying to be, the more likely it is that someone already fixed what you are doing. So basically you are getting punished for beeing detailed.

Comment: Sure, that can be frustrating.  In a couple of instances, I have cut and pasted the bits I am editing into an answer window, so that I can work on them uninterrupted, and then paste them in if I think my edits still have value.  But more frequently, I just abandon the edit for a while, possibly returning to it after the "active period" has died down.   Neither are perfect solutions, I understand.

Comment: @lulu "In cases where an inexperienced user makes a series of minor (usually unhelpful) edits" I think one should not prevent him from doing so. Even if the edits are unhelpful from your point of view they may be useful for the user. He may not me familiar with the editor, markdown , latex and posing  good question, but he will learn a lot when he is trying to improve his question.It is a good mindset to try to pose a question as good as possible. I think it is better to wait and not to interrupt this learning process.

Comment: Related: [Lock a post for editing, or at least display a warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141252/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange

Comment: @miracle173  Oh, if the user is attempting to improve the content, I agree $100\%$.  But in the context of the question, I was only considering formatting.  A typical example would be a user who uses dollar signs to denote currency in the problem without recognizing that this will confuse the system, then notices that the result is unreadable but has no idea why.  No amount of random tinkering will fix the problem...best, I think, to edit and direct the user to examine the syntax that was used.  Any user who wants to learn on their own is free to do so but a garbled question defaces the site.